# Creating user initiated email send definition through API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api

I am able to create email send definitions through SOAP API but not through REST API.

- Through SOAP API I can only create definitions having classic emails and not content builder emails.
- Through Rest API I get response code 201. But it doesn't come up in the marketing Cloud UI.

------Rest API call example -----

```
payload = {
"definitionKey": "APISenddef",
"status": "Active",
"name": "RestAPI_senddef",
"description": "Created via REST",
"classification": "Default Transactional",
"content": {
"customerKey": "3f2d2031-5b3b-4d89-bbfd-f9c40294e9fb"
},
"subscriptions": {
"list": "TestList",
"autoAddSubscriber": True,
"updateSubscriber": True
},
"options": {
"trackLinks": True,
}
}

endpoint = base_api_url + '/messaging/v1/email/definitions'

headers = {
'content-type' : 'application/json', 
'user-agent' : 'Sarthak', 
'authorization' : 
'Bearer ' + authToken}

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

I need to create email send definitions having content builder emails attached. .
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the route POST /messaging/v1/email/definitions is for [transactional messaging api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm), which is newer and doesn't have an UI yet. You would do all actions through the api.

Why are you unable to use Content Builder Emails within a SOAP Call? Content Builder emails also have an email ID, which you can see in the UI:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know earlier that "legacy ID" of the content builder asset corresponds to ID of the email object when using SOAP. I am able to create it using SOAP.